# Visualizing images with text in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a TF model that returns pairs: image and number. I would like to visualize this in tensorboard. I can use `tf.summary.image` for visualizing images and `tf.summary.scalar` for numbers, but I would like to be able to see a bunch of images with their respective numbers at a time.

What is a sensible way to do that? I am currently looking for a way to create an image with a given number from a TF scalar variable and then making two columns of images in tensorboard: one for "real images" and one with the images denoting the scores of respective images -- is it possible to do that easily? Is there a better way?